# ansi_re.append(re.compile(br'\xc0\xa8\x02\x17')) need meaning of the regular expression

Tags: python, regex, ascii

```
ansi_re = TerminalBase.ansi_re
ansi_re.append(re.compile(br'\xc0\xa8\x02\x17'))
```

I need the meaning of the code particular the ASCII values

`\xc0\xa8\x02\x17`

i find the values for last two values but i don't know how the chars works or what kind of value will match the regular expression.

```
02  STX Start of Text
17  ETB End of Transmission Block
```

Give me some examples to match the regular expression

Comment: Are you sure that the `**` characters are in the regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling turned up [this ANSI table](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php)

So to answer your question: The characters you are missing are:

```
C0  À  Latin Capital Letter A With Grave
A8  ¨  Diaeresis
```

And, assuming that the `**` is an error in the regex (as you added them in an edit) would match *exactly* as is. So exactly the string `br'\xc0\xa8\x02\x17'`

again, you should clarify the `**` characters, because they don't make sense in that regex.

Comment: The `br` thing before the quotes is not part of the regex, these are flags for `re.compile()`. `b` is for byte, and `r` is for raw string.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I wanted to stay close to OP's definition. Removing the `r` changes the meaning of the regex ever-so-slightly.

Comment: ... granted... combining `b` *with* `r` for a regex definition feels weird to me.

Answer (score -1):

These are Unicode characters. Console logging them in Javascript shows you (kind of) what string this corresponds to.

**Note:** The below snippet may not render correctly for every user, as this depends on each user's browser encoding.

```js
console.log('\xc0\xa8\x02\x17');
```

**Explanation:**

`\xc0` is the character `À` (`A` with grave accent), used in languages like French

`\xa8` is the diaresis character (two dots that show up above a letter)

The last two characters are the "start of text" and "end of transmission block" respectively. They render as small white spaces when you print them.

Weird string to match against, but there you go.

Comment: Careful with that `console.log`. Python != JavaScript. And in this case, it really depends on the encoding on how the bytes are interpreted.

Comment: Yes, sure. I just used this console log for illustration purposes (can't show Python snippet on SO).

Comment: True. But isn't the result dependent on the current browser-encoding? In any case, `0xc0` and `0xa8` are neither `ASCII` nor `UTF-8` but `ANSI`, or even `LATIN-1`. I'm guessing that the browser somehow falls back to `latin-1` (but that's a wild guess), which is as far as I know not the same as ANSI (but I need to double check that). I would in any case never use `console.log` to test these things. There's too much magic involved.

Comment: Right, I added a note in my answer.

Comment: "These are Unicode characters" -> not exactly - in the question, they are clearly _bytes_

Comment: @snakecharmerb Also, "unicode" does not really mean anything without specifying the encoding. Is it utf-8, utf-16, UCS-4? They are definitely not `utf-8`. Nonetheless, the questions itself hints strongly at `ANSI`, which makes them defintely not unicode.